# DFB LEGO Minifigures

Tags: minifigures

I'm a big fan of LEGO still to this day I was wondering are the DFB LEGO Minifigures available in Los Angeles cause I live there hoping to get the LEGO because they look so great.

[image: DFB minifigs]

Comment: Like Henrik said, I think it was sold exclusively throughout Europe only to cellebrate the world cup champions(I think that was the reason).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that no official retailers outside of Germany+Austria+Switzerland go these. I bought mine on amazon.de.

Answer (score 2):

According to [LEGO's German Store](https://shop.lego.com/en-DE/DFB-The-Mannschaft-71014?s=6137059) it is a:

> Retired Product

So if you're going to find it you'll need to look on ebay, Amazon, or other "unofficial" dealers.